# Generating cron configuration with bash?

Tags: algorithm, bash, cron

In my problem, I will be given a number n. I need to create a cron configuration to run a script as once in  n day.

For example if n=20, script should run once per 20 day.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That configuration is going to be dead ugly, if not impossible to do (you possible have to enumerate each day it will be ever executed..)

It's a lot easier to create a configuration so it's executed every day. Then within the script (or in a *wrapper script*) check that it should actually be executed.

This check can be done with

- arithmetic, something like: `daycounter=$(( ($(date +%s) / (60*60*24) ) % 20))`
- with a state file, which has the creation date that stores the last execution time

The file based solution is more fault-tolerant, if your server is down on the day of the schedule, it's going to execute it the next day, while the arithmetic is scheduled on the next cycle (20 days later).

If you wrap the functionality in a file, your cron entry will look very nice:

```
10 1 * * * executeeveryxday nameofthestatefile 20 "command to execute"
```

Of course if you have more servers and entries, and want to manage this from a central place, perhaps it's better to fetch the tasks from a database..